# Click en Selenium con Phyton

Tags: python, selenium

Hola soy nueva en `Selenium`, mi automatización la estoy desarrollando en `Python`, alguien me puede orientar sobre ejemplos de código para dar click a botones, el código siguiente es al que me manda al darle "inspeccionar elemento" en el botón que requiero:

```
<div id="tabIcon1" class ="workcenterStandard"></div>
```

Mil gracias, saludos!

Comment: Seguramente la documentación oficial te debería de poder orientar.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar encontrar el elemento usando el atributo identificador (id):

```
driver.find_element_by_id('tabIcon1').click()
```

Idealmente, este atributo es unico, pero en caso de que hayan otros elementos con el mismo identificador, se tomara el primero.

[Referencia](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html):

Comment: Saludos, además de incluir la referencia puedes dar un explicación de lo que sugieres, para dar claridad a el usuario que pregunta. ¡Felliz día!